# Heroku error - Failed to install gems via Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I'm making a new deployment to heroku and getting the following error, any ideas on how to fix this? Is bundler broken?

```
    remote:        Downloading countries-1.2.5 revealed dependencies not in the API or the lockfile
remote:        (i18n_data (~> 0.7.0)).
remote:        Either installing with `--full-index` or running `bundle update countries`
remote:        should fix the problem.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the lack of context I'd try updating the gem and retrying, let us know if that works.